# How to view logs related to a python application runs as miniconda environment

Tags: python, miniconda

I need to see the logs that generated from a python application. This python application runs in a miniconda environment.Is there a way I can check the logs ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether I understand the question correctly. In case your application is using logging object (ref. `https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html`) then your output could either be in:

- Console: from which the application was started
- File: in case that you specified the logging output to a file

It depends on your configuration and on the logging level as well. Some applications (like Django) use their own configuration to log.